# Attempting to display globe using React.js and Cesium.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

I've followed every guide I can find on the topic, and none of them seem to be able to help my specific problem.  I can display the the Cesium app on my React webpage, but the globe, background, and thumbnails will not display, however, all of the other widgets will display (home button, time controller, etc.).  If you all need more code, I will be happy to provide more :)

Here is my code:

project/src/App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

import Viewer from "cesium/Source/Widgets/Viewer/Viewer";
import BingMapsImageryProvider from "cesium/Source/Scene/BingMapsImageryProvider";
import CesiumTerrainProvider from "cesium/Source/Core/CesiumTerrainProvider";

const BING_MAPS_URL = "//dev.virtualearth.net";
const BING_MAPS_KEY = process.env.BING_MAPS_KEY;
const STK_TERRAIN_URL = "//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world";

export default class CesiumGlobe extends Component {
  state = {viewerLoaded : false}

  componentDidMount() {
    const imageryProvider = new BingMapsImageryProvider({
        url : BING_MAPS_URL,
        key : BING_MAPS_KEY,
    });

    const terrainProvider = new CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : STK_TERRAIN_URL
    });

    this.viewer = new Viewer(this.cesiumContainer, {
        animation : true,
        baseLayerPicker : false,
        fullscreenButton : false,
        geocoder : false,
        homeButton : true,
        infoBox : false,
        sceneModePicker : false,
        selectionIndicator : true,
        timeline : true,
        navigationHelpButton : false,
        scene3DOnly : true,
        imageryProvider,
        terrainProvider
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.viewer) {
        this.viewer.destroy();
    }
  }
  render() {
    const containerStyle = {
       const containerStyle = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        position: 'fixed',
        display : "flex",
        alignItems : "stretch",
    };

    const widgetStyle = {
        flexGrow : 2
    }

    return (
        <div className="cesiumGlobeWrapper" style={containerStyle}>
            <div
                className="cesiumWidget"
                ref={ element => this.cesiumContainer = element }
                style={widgetStyle}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I generated the BingMapsApi key very recently, so this likely isn't the issue.

Comment: Are there any errors in the web console or network tab?

Comment: @emackey Yes, it couldn't find cesium/Assets/approximateTerrainHeights.json or cesium/Assets/IAU2006_XYS/IAU2006_XYS_15.json but both are included in two places